# How do I update the state of Flutter widget based on variable value

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying update a widget when I change the value of alive to true/false.  I can not get this to work.  If I replace the widgets in the List it updates correctly, but this is not what I want to do.  I want to be able to just update the value of the object and have it change state based on the value.  I don't know flutter/dart so need some clues.

```
void _increment() {
  setState(() {
      gol.tick();
      //squares.clear();
      for (var x = 0; x < gol.cols; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < gol.rows; y++) {
          //squares.add( Square(alive: gol.grid.get(x, y)));
          squares[x+y].alive = gol.grid.get(x, y);
        }
      }
    });
}
```

Square Widget code.

```
class Square extends StatefulWidget {
  bool alive = false;
  Square({ super.key, required this.alive});

  @override
  State<Square> createState() => _SquareState();
}

class _SquareState extends State<Square> {

  Color getColor() {
    if (widget.alive) {
      return Colors.grey[800]!;
    }
    return Colors.grey[100]!;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: getColor(),
    );
  }
}
```

Use case:

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: GridView.count(
           physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
           crossAxisCount: 10,
           children: [...squares])
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _increment,
        tooltip: 'Tick',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), 
    );
```

Comment: Can you include the sample usecase widget for `Square`

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: Can you include how you are using `Square` widget. It will easier if you can provide another test widget that will reproduce the same issue

Comment: I think this has to do with List equality, adding a new widget automatically means it is not equal to the previous one and therefore state is changed, but when you change the value inside the object inside the list then that would be difficult for dart to check unless you add a `equals` override for your object

Comment: I added how I am using the "Square" List.

Comment: @gtxtreme - I kind of understand what you are saying.  Would you mean override equals in List or in Square?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, in Flutter it's usually best not to call setstate except to update values. So all of your code logic that you have inside of setstate should be moved and setstate should only be called when you want to update a value.

Comment: @slackwars do it for your `Square` model, it should start working